# Does Tensorflow have SVR packages like sklearn.svm.SVR in scikit-learn?

Tags: tensorflow, svm

I am new to Tensorflow, I wonder whether Tensorflow has ready-to-use SVR packages like sklearn.svm.SVR in scikit-learn. Or I have to build the SVR on my own?

Comment: It is unfortunate that TF has not spent more time developing SVRs for its platform. I guess they don't see the potential as we do.  Anyway, you could look into [scikit-flow](https://www.kdnuggets.com/2016/02/scikit-flow-easy-deep-learning-tensorflow-scikit-learn.html), it seems like an interesting alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Tensorflow now seems to incorporate [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn)

I'm stilling looking into it as I have a SKLearn SVR that I would really like to have access to more processing power via tensorflow. I'll let you know if I figure this out.

**Edit:** Also Found [this little nugget of info](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/g3doc/svm.md)